# ui-router: если 50 страниц и более - в конфиге писать портянку?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Здравствуйте. Наставьте на путь истинный.
Читал, смотрел, искал. Везде пишут одно и то же, везде стандартный набор.

```
    .state("home", {
        url: "/"
        ,templateUrl: "/src/modules/page/views/index.html"
    })
    .state("profile", {
        url: "/profile"
        ,templateUrl: "/src/modules/page/views/profile.html"
    })
    .state("games", {
        url: "/games"
        ,templateUrl: "/src/modules/page/views/games.html"
    })
    .state("settings", {
        url: "/settings"
        ,templateUrl: "/src/modules/page/views/settings.html"
    })
```

А если у меня будет много страниц, мне для каждой точно так же надо будет прописывать? Неужели нет динамического решения?

Опять же на каждый стейт придется еще добавлять views, а в нем хедер, футер, меню и сайдбар.

Comment: для выполнения однотипных операций используют цикл

Comment: @Grundy а вариант что-то типа такого? .state(name, {url: "/"+name})

Comment: да, примерно так, в приведенном примере кода стейты довольно однотипные

Comment: @Grundy, не подскажете, где посмотреть самые различные варианты исполнения? Может есть где-нибудь коллекция от простых до эксклюзивных?

Comment: не совсем понял, что имеется ввиду?

Comment: Варианты написания .state(), потому что я встречал всякие разные, а как они работают не всегда описано и мне не понятно.

Comment: лучше чем в [справке](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router) вряд ли можно найти